# Can I add a second occupant to a hotel room at check-in?

Tags: uk, hotels

I have a business trip to London, and have booked my hotel through my employer.  It's a large multinational so it has its own internal system for booking, meaning that I don't have full control over the booking process (such as, the number of occupants).  However, it's a large double room, so I see no problem with bringing my girlfriend along with me.  I can't add her to the booking in advance due to the restrictions of my employer's booking system but:

- Can I simply inform the hotel during check-in that I wish to add an additional occupant?
- Is there any risk of my employer being charged extra for this?
- Alternatively, would it be risky to simply not inform the hotel about her and get her to sit somewhere else while I check in?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In most hotels, that's perfectly fine. In some hotels they might charge you extra especially if breakfast is included. That also varies a bit with location but I think I've seen both in London.

> Can I simply inform the hotel during check-in that I wish to add an additional occupant?

Yes. It may be better to call ahead and ask. This gives you more leverage and less stress on the travel day.

> Is there any risk of my employer being charged extra for this?

Depends on the hotel. You can just try to do an online booking at that hotel for 1 and for 2 persons and see if there is any difference. Many employer do have provision for this in their travel policy: in most cases that's perfectly fine and there is way to handle extra expenses (if they occur).

> Alternatively, would it be risky to simply not inform the hotel about her and get her to sit somewhere else while I check in?

Technically you are violating the terms and conditions of your booking. Whether the hotel will find out or care is anyone's guess. One downside is that you may only have one room key, so your girlfriend can't easily go out on her own while you are at work. It feels sneaky, I wouldn't do it.

Look, what  you are trying to do here is perfectly normal and legitimate. Just ask the hotel and the employer how best to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the information and advice, that's really helpful!

Comment: In some hotels, even a double room will not necessarily get the same preparation depending on the number of guests booked. This may notably affect the number of towels and, where provided, bathrobes, slippers, toiletries, free bottles of water, etc. This can partially explain the difference even when the breakfast is not included. So probably better to advise the hotel in advance. Also check any corporate travel rules on the topic. While I doubt they would prevent you from having your partner in the room if it doesn’t cost extra, you never know what HR or accounts may have come up with…

Comment: I think in the UK it is very common that booking a double room for 2 people costs more than booking the same room for a single person. As such, I would expect a surcharge.

Comment: @jcaron I'm surprised when that's *not* the case, especially in the budget places where I tend to stay, that do try fairly obviously to minimise their costs.  Staying solo I get enough towels for at least two, often in practice more

Comment: Thanks for the advice everyone, I took @Hilmar's advice and rang the hotel, they were totally fine and took my partner's details.  No extra cost.

Comment: +1 but I’d note that in my experience hotels often give you two cards even for one person and you get more than enough towels no matter what.

Comment: If asked politely and in advance Id wager most hospitals would also allow separately billing any additional charges, which would ease any potential conflict with your employer

Comment: @Hobbamok [A hospital...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLpBtDRkuD8)

Comment: Not informing the hotel could technical be a tax violation. In many places in Europe, hotel guests are expected to pay "city tax". There are many ways city tax can be calculated, but a common one is a fixed price per person/per night.

Comment: Not recommending going behind the hotel’s back, and the issue has been solved anyways, but room keys have never been a problem for me. Even when travelling alone, I always ask for two key cards for the door (because I _hate_ the way the power completely turns off in most hotel rooms as soon as you take the key card out of the holder thingy, preventing you from charging your laptop/camera/phone while you’re not in the room), and I have never had a hotel ask questions or refuse that.

Comment: It might also be against company policy. For example, at my current employer (a university in Sweden), they would expect you to pay for half the room out of pocket if shared with a partner. I believe the reason is mostly taxation - Sweden tends to be rather obnoxious about employers providing any benefits to employees that do not show up on the employee's tax statements.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I had a hotel refuse a couple of times Mostly in Italy and Greece. In that case simply unplug the fridge or the TV and use that outlet for the charger. Fridge outlets are almost never tied into the card-presence system and TV's in many cases also not.

Comment: @Tonny most (90%) of the time the electricity card-slot is just a mechanical connection (i.e. it doesn't read the card), so any card can work - try it with any old plastic card (finally a use for the blockbusters membership card which has been in your wallet since 2018), or even just a piece of paper or card next time you are only given a single card.

Comment: @NeilTarrant That works too, but hotel cleaning staff has an annoying tendency to remove the dummy card when you do that in my experience....

Comment: @JonathanReez-onstrike on the other hand, I have also been to enough hotels where we were two people and only got one key. Quite common when they are actual keys as opposed to cards.

Comment: Wow... Never heard of power going off when you leave the room. Lights maybe, but outlets too? Sheesh! My experience (primarily US) is that they'll issue you all the keys you want when you check in, give you towels just by calling the front desk (or stopping by), and that _usually_ an additional guest isn't an issue at all. I have, in my younger days, crowded 6-10 people (sometimes more!) in one hotel room (with only 2 people officially there) - I realize that was strictly verboten. Being young and broke didn't excuse it, but we did anyway...

Comment: @FreeMan: this varies greatly across the globe. You rarely find keycard switches in the US but they are quite common in Asia, specifically where it's hot. One of the purposes is to not run the Air Condition when no one is in the room. Energy conservation has much lower priority in the US compared to most other countries.

Comment: @Tonny I used a bank card in one hotel, the cleaning staff removed it but left it clearly visible.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That was lucky. I wouldn't dare to use a real bank-card. The 3 or 4  times that I used a bonus/membership-card (that looks like a bank-card if you're not familiar with the retail-store it belongs too) that I happened to have in my wallet they threw it away. Lucky for me none of them was important. I can only assume that a bank-card would get the same treatment.